# Why AppointmentItem's send event will be called many times?

Tags: outlook, vsto

I add an event handler to every `AppointmentItem`'s send event. This event handler just do some logging thing. I create a meeting through Outlook 2003, and then update the meeting twice. At last I check the log.

```cs
this.Application.Inspectors.NewInspector += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(_inspectors_NewInspector);

private void _inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector inspector)
{
    if(inspector.CurrentItem is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
    {
        _appointmentEvent = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event;
        _appointmentEvent.Send += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_SendEventHandler(_appointmentEvent_Send);
    }
}

private void _appointmentEvent_Send(ref bool Cancel)
{
    Log.WriteLog("InspectorWrapper: _appointmentEvent_Send Enter");
    Log.WriteLog("InspectorWrapper: _appointmentEvent_Send Exit");
}
```

I check the log. I found that send event handler will be called many times.

> 2012-05-16 10:07:21:066: InspectorWrapper: _appointmentEvent_Send Enter
>       2012-05-16 10:07:21:067: InspectorWrapper: _appointmentEvent_Send Exit
>       ...
>       2012-05-16 10:07:27:281: InspectorWrapper: _appointmentEvent_Send Enter
>       2012-05-16 10:07:27:283: InspectorWrapper: _appointmentEvent_Send Exit
>       2012-05-16 10:07:27:283: InspectorWrapper: _appointmentEvent_Send Enter
>       2012-05-16 10:07:27:284: InspectorWrapper: _appointmentEvent_Send Exit
>       ...
>       2012-05-16 10:07:32:607: InspectorWrapper: _appointmentEvent_Send Enter
>       2012-05-16 10:07:32:608: InspectorWrapper: _appointmentEvent_Send Exit
>       2012-05-16 10:07:32:609: InspectorWrapper: _appointmentEvent_Send Enter
>       2012-05-16 10:07:32:609: InspectorWrapper: _appointmentEvent_Send Exit
>       2012-05-16 10:07:32:610: InspectorWrapper: _appointmentEvent_Send Enter
>       2012-05-16 10:07:32:610: InspectorWrapper: _appointmentEvent_Send Exit

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add logging to the `NewInspector` event to see how many times you latch onto the `AppointmentItem.Send` event. My assumption is that `NewInspector` is your issue. It is best practice to manage a list of active inspectors using a custom `InspectorWrapper` as a container to avoid multiple event latching.

For reference, take a look at `FindOutlookInspector` from [this MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226712.aspx#officeoutlookribbon__modifycode).

```cs
internal static List<OutlookInspector> m_Windows;       
internal static OutlookInspector FindOutlookInspector(object window)
{
    foreach (OutlookInspector inspector in m_Windows)
        if (inspector.Window == window)
            return inspector;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your notice. NewInspector just means this inspector window is new, it does not mean AppointmentItem is new, maybe this AppointmentItem has been loaded many times.